# How do I make git autocomplete work in byobu

Tags: byobu

I used to git cli interface and when I type `git s` and press `show` git autocomplete script will prompt me with options `show` and `status`

It does work in tmux.
It does not work in byobu session. Byobu prompt me local files.

Comment: What shell are you using? (`echo $0`) And which operating system? Both information are missing

Comment: /bin/bash OSX, but can observe it on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion OS X or Ubuntu? Not sure if this will work as you wrote that it works in tmux. byobu should recognize the completion actually by default.

Comment: both installed, maybe that's terminal related? I've tried iterm2 and terminal.app

Comment: but as it is working in raw tmux, I assume something is wrong with byobu keybindings?

Comment: ok, those were not keybinding but prompt related, thanks for questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I've used customized byobu prompt. So I can either disable it via `byobu-disable-prompt` or configure it so it will use bash completion also by adding this line `. ~/.bash_profile` to `~/.byobu/prompt`

Answer (score 0):

In Centos bash_completion scripts were at `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`

so sourcing this file inside byobu prompt solved the issue.

```sh
echo ". /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" >> ~/.byobu/prompt
```

exit and start your byobu session again and it should work.